# Why won't OAuth work on web server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I have an ASP.Net web application running on Windows Server 2012, and need to make calls to social networking sites using oauth to generate some of the page content.  Everything works on my development machine, but I can't even get a single response back ("unable to connect to the remote server" error).

I disabled the firewall to test that.  No luck.  I created a console application to test it that way.  A simple HttpWebRequest will get the html for any page I throw at it, but not any oauth request.  I've used different libraries to try to achieve this, including Linq2Twitter, Spring.Social, and HigLabo.  All work locally, but not on the server.  I've found nothing useful in the server event log.

Can anyone give me some clues what might be happening?

EDIT: Here's some code I'm using with the HigLabo library to try to retrieve the user timeline.

```
using HigLabo.Net.Twitter;
var cl = new TwitterClient(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
var rr = cl.GetHomeTimeline();
foreach (var r in rr)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(r.CreatedAt + ":" + r.Text);
}
```

I'm aware that accessToken & accessTokenSecret aren't/shouldn't be necessary for a simple timeline read, but this is just to make sure it works first.

Comment: what isn't responding to what?

Comment: No HttpWebResponse from the HttpWebRequest ("unable to connect to the remote server") after timeout.

Comment: that request is going from where to where?  urls

Comment: Request is being sent to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

Comment: that's after you've got the oauth token?  if so, why is this question titled "oauth"?  if not, why are you calling this url before getting a token?

Comment: I'm not making the calls through my code.  I'm doing it through the libraries (listed above).  I tried 3 of them to see if I got any differences.  The url I listed I got by tracing code through the downloaded HigLabo library.  Again, this all works (using the exact same keys/secrets) on my dev. machine.  Just not on the server.

Comment: Editing question to include some code I'm using.

Comment: I don't know why the question was downvoted, it was a legitimate search for an answer to a problem.  Downvotes should be accompanied by a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a firewall issue, as had been suspected.  But not the server firewall.  This was a problem with the ISP.  They had an internal firewall that was blocking all traffic to/from the social network sites.  They were able to resolve it quickly with a phonecall, but it was not a coding or configuration error on my part.